# Transferring MAMP SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a question regarding PhPMyadmin and MAMP. I am currently working on developing a website that uses a database to store data. However, when I finish developing locally on MAMP, how would I go about transferring the already existing database to the new location (where usually I can access it also on PhPmyadmin, but it's on an actual hosting company let's say).
I hope I made the question clear. I would appreciate detailed description but just main steps or points to achieve this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database exporting is common in every OS's PHPMyAdmin .

```
1. Select the database.
2. Click Export tab in PHPMyAdmin
3. In that, Select export method. There will be two options. "Quick" is the default option.
4. Select export database format. Normally "SQL" is default.
5. Click "Go" button. Your selected database will be exported as SQL format.
```

You can import this database into your destination.